# How to contact a specific label and change one of its programs (for example its bg). Instead of producing a new one I want to update an old one

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

class Information():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.load_dict_label()
        self.display()

    def display(self):
        for i in self.location_and_condition_label:
            bg_to_label = self.location_and_condition_label[i]["color"]
            row_to_label = self.location_and_condition_label[i]["row"]
            column_to_label = self.location_and_condition_label[i]["column"]
            text_to_label = self.location_and_condition_label[i]["text"]
            
            self.i = Label(self.master, font=("Courier", 14), text= text_to_label, bg=bg_to_label).grid(row=row_to_label, column=column_to_label, padx=5, pady=5)
```

For the example I chose random values.

```
def load_dict_label(self):
    color = "red"
    self.location_and_condition_label = {
        "0000": {"column": 0, "row": 0, "text": "5:00", "color": color},
        "0001": {"column": 1, "row": 0, "text": "Getting up", "color": color},
        "0002": {"column": 2, "row": 0, "text": "Wash face", "color": color},
        "0003": {"column": 3, "row": 0, "text": "Get dress", "color": color},
        "0004": {"column": 0, "row": 1, "text": "6:00", "color": color},
        "0005": {"column": 1, "row": 1, "text": "Drink coffee", "color": color},
        "0006": {"column": 2, "row": 1, "text": "Read  newspaper", "color": color},
        "0007": {"column": 0, "row": 2, "text": "7:00", "color": color},
        "0008": {"column": 1, "row": 2, "text": "Turn on tv", "color": color},
        "0009": {"column": 2, "row": 2, "text": "Drink coffee", "color": color},
        "0010": {"column": 3, "row": 2, "text": "Wake the child", "color": color},
        "0011": {"column": 4, "row": 2, "text": "Organize the\n child", "color": color},
        "0012": {"column": 5, "row": 2, "text": "Make us \nbreakfast", "color": color},
        "0013": {"column": 0, "row": 3, "text": "8:00", "color": color},
        "0014": {"column": 1, "row": 3, "text": "To go \nto work", "color": color},
        "0015": {"column": 2, "row": 3, "text": "Say hello to\neveryone", "color": color},
        "0016": {"column": 0, "row": 4, "text": "9:00", "color": color},
        "0017": {"column": 1, "row": 4, "text": "Make a morning\ncall", "color": color},
        "0018": {"column": 2, "row": 4, "text": "Start working", "color": color},
        "0019": {"column": 3, "row": 4, "text": "Drink coffee", "color": color}
    }
```

This function I want to change that instead of producing a new one I want to update an old function and display on window.

```
    def update_label(self):
        self.location_and_condition_label["0010"]["color"] = "green"
        self.display()

class MainPanel():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self._master = master
        self._master.configure(background="#929591")
        self._nformation = Information(self._master)
        self.running = True

    def run(self):
        if self.running == True:
            self._nformation.update_label()

        self._master.after(5000, app.run)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Tk()
    app = MainPanel(root)
    root.after(5000, app.run)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just save the labels in a dictionary, and then use the `configure` method to change them.

Comment: I could not save ('self.i')  the labels to dictionary.

Comment: You can use something like `self.labels[i] = Label(...)` and add `self.labels = {}` before the for loop.  Also you need to split `Label(...).grid(...)` into two lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the labels in a dictionary, and then use the `configure` method to change the color.

```
def display(self):
    for i in self.location_and_condition_label:
        ... 
        label = Label(self.master, font=("Courier", 14), text= text_to_label, bg=bg_to_label)
        label.grid(row=row_to_label, column=column_to_label, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.labels[i] = label

def update_label(self):
    self.location_and_condition_label["0002"]["color"] = "green"
    self.labels["0002"].configure(background="green")
```

Things to notice:

- the creation of the label and calling `grid` are separate, so that `label` is set to the actual label widget
- we add the label to a dictionary named `self.labels`
- `update_label` does not need to call `display`, since `display` creates new labels each time it is called. Instead, we call the `configure` method on the specific label

Alternately, you could modify `display` to only create the widget if it doesn't exist, and then always use `configure` to update it to the current specification. The solution would then look something like this:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self.labels = {}  # initialize self.labels to an empty dictionary
    self.load_dict_label()
    self.display()

def display(self):
    for i in self.location_and_condition_label:
        ...
        if i not in self.labels:
            # create the label if it hasn't been created
            label = Label(self.master, font=("Courier", 14))
            label.grid(row=row_to_label, column=column_to_label, padx=5, pady=5)
            self.labels[i] = label

        # update the label with the stored configuration values
        self.labels[i].configure(
            text= text_to_label, bg=bg_to_label
        )

def update_label(self):
    self.location_and_condition_label["0002"]["color"] = "green"
    self.display()
```